# Picture Book with a Ghost House with No Door

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Around 1982, I got a picture book of connected ghost stories out of the library.  I don't remember much about it, except that there were some elements in the first story that were rather striking.

There was a frame story about a boy and an older relative (probably his grandfather).  There was a horrible storm going on outside, and they discussed what it would be like to be caught out in it.  The boy said that he would probably just hide under a log and wait to die of exposure, but his grandfather said, *No, I was out in a storm like this once, and I tried to find shelter, but I met all sorts of frightening things along the way*.  (That's not a direct quote.)  The stories in the book were of the monsters and horrors that he encountered, starting on the night when he had been caught in that furious storm.

The first story is the only one I really remember a bit about.  The grandfather related that he came to a house, but he knew it was the house of a ghost, because it had no door.  There was an illustration of the ghost entering of leaving the house through the chimney, but I cannot recall much else.

Does anybody know what book this was?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Grandpa's Ghost Stories](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1244278.Grandpa_s_Ghost_Stories) by James Flora

> Sitting on Grandpa's lap in the middle of a thunderstorm and listening
>   to weird stories about what happened to him as a boy is not quite as
>   cozy as it sounds. Skeletons in sacks; horrible witches; huge, scary,
>   furry spiders with big, squishy mouths; hideous ghosts and hungry
>   werewolves haunted Grandpa in one terrible predicament after another.
>   A skeleton chased him into the Warty Witch's cave where she turned him
>   into a spider with her magic wishbone and, after landing in a few more
>   scary adventures, wished himself right back to his own house.
>   Grandpa's tall tales leave the reader with a happy memory of shivers,
>   gasps and chuckles.

"The House of the Ghastly Ghost" is the third one:

> There were no doors or windows in this house. Right away I
>   knew that it had to be the house of a ghost. Ghosts don't need doors or windows. They use the chimney.

There are some inside pictures [here](http://www.silvershoesandrabbitholes.com/2014/10/grandpas-ghost-stories.html). For example. the house with no door:
[image: Page with the house with no door]